# Where to add script in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

Where to add script in Angular2

Comment: I am not familiar with Nebular (I did look it up though), but check out the [angular cli](https://cli.angular.io/) project, that may help you? Additionally, it's difficult to tell what you are asking as there are many types of files you can add to the project.

Comment: what type of script you want to add?

Comment: Nebular-akveo not angular 2 template its angulat 5

Comment: @VeluDhanesh JS- javascript

Comment: After looking through some documentation, if you following what it says on the doc site, you should have no issue.  It also depends if you're adding to your own app or just want to get their test app up and running.  Here's the link for the documentation: https://akveo.github.io/nebular/?utm_source=github&utm_medium=nebular_readme#/docs/installation/add-into-existing-project

Comment: Again, there are components, modules, and services. Check out https://angular.io/tutorial if you are new to angular and https://angular.io/guide/styleguide if you need more guidance on where to place files.

Answer (score 0):

Go to angular-cli.json

And add your scripts on the scripts json, example:

```
"apps":
[...
"scripts":
[
"scripts/yourScript.js"
]
]
```

This will then bundle your script into the main bundle.